# PHP/AJAX simple ready up room

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

What is the best solution to this: one player enters name and creates a room name. Other players enter a name and the room name the first user created. They all join the room and it shows a list of all the users that have joined in real time. As soon as all players have hit the ready button, it switched them to a new page. What would be the most effective way of doing this? Ajax? And if so, is there a tutorial I could check out to break down how it works. Thanks. I'm used to normal php and html stuff lol

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the guide to [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: suggest use websocket it's two way messaging, when u want people in room see other people's ready state, ajax may need more coding and waste